# Reading multiple .properties files for a single application(client) from spring cloud config server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have to set up a spring cloud config server that helps me externalize the properties files for spring-boot applications. My spring-boot applications have multiple `@RestController` classes, and each of this class has a separate `.properties` file.

As per my knowledge, the `.properties` file is accessed as `{service}-{profile}.properties`

`{service}` is set using `$spring.application.name` on the clients side.

But in my case this would restrict me to a single controller within the application being able to get its properties, because I have multiple `.properties` files (one corresponding to each controller within the application).

eg.

I have an application named School. I have a separate controller for the Student and a different one for the Teacher and both have their separate `.properties` files. How can I read both these files dynamically as both have different names

Answer (score 0):

@PropertySource annotation don't fit your requirements ?